# Virtualization enabled in BIOS but IntelPIU not recognize

Tags: cpu, bios, windows-11, asus, virtualization-based-security

I recently buy an asus tuf dash f15 2022, it came with I7-12650H and is running with W11.

The processor's specifications says that VTx, Hyperthreading, and VTd it has it, in the BIOS they are enabled but when I'm running Intel Processor Identification Utility, they don't appear, I have already disabled Hyper V, and everything related with virtualization from Windows Features

[image: WindowsFeaturesImage]

Also disabled Device Guard from Local Group Policy Editor and disable memory integrity from core isolation.

[image: DeviceGuardDisabled]
[image: MemoryIntegrityDisabled]

But the laptop still showing Virtualization-bases security Running.

[image: VBSRunning]

I don't know what else can I do, so I turn to you and your experience.

Comment: Typically when this happens you have some other software using hardware virtualization, when this happens, tools to determine if VT-x is enabled will erroneously indicate its disabled

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution.

4. Disable Windows Defender Credential Guard

reg delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" /v "LsaCfgFlags" /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard" /v "LsaCfgFlags"  /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard" /v "EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity" /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard" /v "RequirePlatformSecurityFeatures" /f

mountvol X: /s
copy %WINDIR%\System32\SecConfig.efi X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi /Y
bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} device partition=X:
mountvol X: /d

5. Disable Virtualization-Based Security

bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS
bcdedit /set vsmlaunchtype off

6. Restart PC and confirm changes

After a reboot, before the system boots, you will be asked whether to disable Windows Defender Credential Guard and Virtualization-Based Security.

You must confirm everything with the Windows button.

All the credits for: Konrad Drozd
https://kdrozd.pl/slow-virtualbox-virtual-machine/

Comment: While it is great you found a solution, this site doesn’t like link-only answers like this. Is there any way you can summarize what is on the linked site and still link to it as well for reference?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).